# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Есть Services.class:

```
public class Services extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isRunning(Class<?> serviceClass)  {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))  {
            if(serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Когда вызываю функцию isRunning с MainActivity:

```
services.isRunning(ForegroundServiceEarningMoney.class)
```

выдаёт ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.Object
>   android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference

В чём проблема?

Comment: Как вы получили ссылку на экземпляр сервиса в активности? Надеюсь не так: `services = new Services();`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```
public static boolean isRunning(Context context, String className)  {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    assert manager != null;
    for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))  {
        if(className.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

И вызов

```
    boolean isRun = isRunning(getApplicationContext(),TestService.class.getName());
    log.debugLog(this, isRun ? "RUN" : "NOT RUN");
```